# How to stop query lock in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

my website was in codeigniter 1.7 previously so now we upgraded to ci 3.x and my queries are locking which creates lot queue and system comes to shutdown at end due to lot of locked queries how to handle this was not in codeigniter 1.7 following are my session settings

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_customer_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 3600;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

this is one of example from lock and after that all queries get locked
SELECT GET_LOCK('e704c41d89df5626e7b8427def8360eb', 300) AS ci_session_lock
```

please help this is effecting my business.

Comment: There are a lot of changes between CodeIgniter 1.7 and 3.x. There are [upgrade instructions](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrading.html). Run your code on a test system and walk through all the upgrade instructions.

Comment: i read and then update the system and system working problem is only queries locking